# How can I do a url redirect to include a wordpress username?

Tags: users, redirect, urls

I currently have a button like this, that takes a user to their 'mentions' page

```
<a href="http://my.url.org/mentions/<?php global $userdata;
get_currentuserinfo(); echo( $userdata->user_login );?>">button</a>
```

What I'd like instead is that a user can see their 'mentions' when they log in to the page. so I'd like admin to be redirected to http://my.url.org/mentions/admin when he goes to a particular page (i.e. the homepage) - I think this would be best using a PHP redirect?

How could I do this?

Comment: How is the "mentions" page output? Can you post the code for that page? Is this related to the P2 theme? If so, posting on their forums might give you insight as well.

Comment: Yeah it was related to the p2 theme, however @pogoking has managed to solve the issue, thank you though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add action to, for example, `template_redirect` action hook. The action would perform your desired checks and redirect user using the [`wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) function. The code could look something like this:

```
function my_redirect_function() {
    // Check if home page is being displayed
    if ( is_home() ) {
        global $userdata;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $username = $userdata->user_login;
        $url = 'http://my.url.org/mentions/' . $username;

        wp_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_redirect_function' );
```

You place whatever checks (such as [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)) you'd like instead of `is_home()` check.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked fantastically. Great explanation and links to conditional tags really helped, I've implemented this and it works! :)

Comment: @ameeromar Great to hear that. You can always mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: is that the little tick? - I've done now... bit of an obscure button!